# How do I output a PDF file using Perl's Mason?

Tags: perl, file-io, mason

I have to write taking a code from the .pdf file, and copy it to anyother pdf file. The code i have written to open the file is given as under :

```
<%args>
$fullname
$filename

</%args>
<%init>
use IO::File;

$r->content_type('application/pdf');
$r->header_out( 'Content-disposition' => "attachment; filename=$filename" );


my $tmpfile = $filename;
my $forread = new IO::File "< $fullname";

my @lines = <$forread>;


foreach my $key (@lines){ 
      print $key;
       }

return $fullname;

</%init>
```

where filename is the name for the file to save the pdf content to and "fullname" is the pdf getting the content from

Answer (score 2):

You're currently reading in a text file. You should `binmode` first for non-text (like PDF). And, never use *indirect object syntax*.

```
my $fh = IO::File->new($fullname, 'r');

$fh->binmode(1);
```

So try something like this, adapted from the [Mason Book](http://www.masonbook.com/book/chapter-7.mhtml#TOC-ANCHOR-9).

```
use Apache::Constants qw(OK);

my $fh = IO::File->new($fullname, 'r');

$fh->binmode(1);

$m->clear_buffer; # avoid extra output (but it only works when autoflush is off)

$r->content_type('application/pdf');
$r->send_http_header;

while ( my $data = $fh->getline ) {
    $m->print($data);
}
$fh->close;

$m->abort;
```